# Lagrangian mechanics a cylinder on a cylinder barrel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics

[image: sketch]

This is a typical problem to be solved using the Lagrangian mechanics, but I have a problem in understanding the rotational energy.

The task is to formulate the Lagrangian equation for the system of the cylinder (mass density $\rho=const$) rolling on the barrel of the bigger cylinder.
So $L=T-V$ and $T=T_\text{translation}+T_\text{rotation}$. The translational energy is $$T_\text{trans}=\frac{m}{2}(R-r)^2 \dot{\phi}.$$
The problem begins with the rotational energy. The solution states it is $$T_\text{rot}=\frac{1}{2}J_s(\dot{\phi} + \dot{\theta})^2$$
with $J_s=\frac{1}{2}m r^2$. I don´t understand why it´s not solved using the parallel axis theorem $J=J_s+md^2$ with $d=(R-r)$, because it´s a mass that rotates on an axis parallel to the centre of gravity by a shift of $(R-r)$ and around itself. That´s my solution using this theorem:
\begin{align}
T_\text{rot}&= \frac{1}{2}J \dot{\phi}+\frac{1}{2}J_s \dot{\theta}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}m r^2+m(R-r)^2\right)\dot{\phi}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}m r^2\right)\dot{\theta}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}mr^2\left(\dot{\phi}^2 + \dot{\theta}^2\right)+\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2 m(R-r)^2
\end{align}
But that's not the right solution I guess by looking at the solution. I hope someone can clear up why using the parallel axis theorem seems to be wrong here. The last part of $T_{rot}$ could be the translational energy, but the $\frac{1}{4}mr^2(\dot{\phi}^2+ \dot{\theta}^2)$ does not match to the given solution $T_\text{rot}=\frac{1}{4}mr^2(\dot{\phi} + \dot{\theta})^2$.